# python install scrapy - failed with error code 1

Tags: python, scrapy, lxml

I tried to install scrapy by "pip install scrapy", and I got:

```
c:\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\tzvia\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
07h63108\\Twisted\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', 
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record 
C:\Users\tzvia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hy8qkma1\install-record.txt 
--single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 
in C:\Users\tzvia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-07h63108\Twisted\
```

I tried "conda install -c conda-forge scrapy" and it seems like the scrapy already installed:

```
C:\Users\tzvia>conda install -c conda-forge scrapy
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

so I tried using scrapy and go an error:

```
C:\Users\tzvia>scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\tzvia\Anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 6, in 
<module>
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
File "C:\Users\tzvia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\__init__.py", line 
34, in <module>
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
File "C:\Users\tzvia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
from scrapy.http import Request
File "C:\Users\tzvia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
File "C:\Users\tzvia\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 11, in <module>
import lxml.html
File "C:\Users\tzvia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", 
line 54, in <module>
from .. import etree
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried to install lxml, and got again "failed with error code 1".

can someone help me?
I use python 3.6.1 and windows 10

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because your Twisted install failed.
Download the Twisted .whl file from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted .

Then run

```
pip install <Twisted-your-version.whl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing lxml on Windows can be a bit of pain.

You might want to check out the info they have on their site [here](https://lxml.de/3.6/installation.html#installation). They suggest that if building from source fails you might want to use the unofficial pre-built binaries by downloading from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) and then running

```
python -m pip install .\lxml-4.2.5-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
```

Make sure to download the version that you need. If you're using python 3.6 you should get the `cp36` one.

Answer (score -1):

Forget about **pip install**! The issue with 'scrapy' is all over the Web. Download 'Scrapy-2.5.0.tar.gz' (or whatever version is current) from https://pypi.org/project/Scrapy/, exract it to a temp folder and run **< python  setup.py install >**